# Under the hood of Dispatcher

Tags: wpf

Aloha everybody,

I have few concerns about Dispatcher.

As far I understood that thingy a Dispather is the UI thread therefore when I use Dispatcher.Invoke I let the UI wait till my operation is done.

Now my question is does the UI wait when I use BeginInvoke method which is async?

What is the "Normal" priority of Dispatcher? Does it mean it executes my operation immediately?

When I only call BeginInvoke without DispatcherProprity which default properity will dispatcher assocciate to my operation?

Now lets combine Normal priority with BeginInvoke. Will dispatcher execute then my operation imediately async or what happens exactly there under the hood?

I apologize in case this question is a duplicate.

Comment: In the current format, this question is not a good fit for SO. It's unlikely someone here will provide an answer that is better than simply reading Microsoft's overview of the dispatcher and threading model on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx), the `Dispatcher`

> Provides services for managing the queue of work items for a thread.

So calling `Invoke` on one does *not* necessarily have any immediate effect... it simply adds your request onto the queue - this does *not* mean that your request will be performed immediately.

The `DispatcherProprity` value tells the Framework where to put the request in the queue. Calling `Invoke` with a high priority will result in your request being placed in the queue at a high level, just *after* any other requests that have that same priority.

Regarding calls to `BeginInvoke`, the only real difference is that the

> control returns immediately to the calling object after it is called.

As far as I'm aware, everything else including priority is the same.